# Staggered Grid View Not scrolling inside Listview

Tags: flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-sliver, flutter-listview, flutter-gridview

[image]

Red color one is carousal view
Green color one is horizontal ListView
Blue color one is Staggered Gridview widget

So My issue is Staggered Grid View is not srolling up inside Listview

I want to scroll all Content . Any one please help this . My code is :

**
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
return Scaffold(

    body: ListView(
      physics: new AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      primary: true,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0),
      children: <Widget>[
        CarouselSlider(
          height: 180,
          //height: double.infinity,
          //aspectRatio: 16/9,
          viewportFraction: 0.94,
          initialPage: 0,
          enlargeCenterPage: true,
          autoPlay: false,
          reverse: false,
          enableInfiniteScroll: false,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          onPageChanged: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _current = index;
            });
          },
          items: imgList.map((imgUrl) {
            return Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Container(
                  width: 400,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                    child: Image.network(
                      imgUrl,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,

                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 2,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: map<Widget>(imgList, (index, url) {
            return Container(
              width: 8.0,
              height: 8.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: _current == index ? Colors.grey : Colors.black,
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0,bottom: 10.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Latest Markers',textAlign: TextAlign.left ,overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 22.0),)
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0, vertical: 0.0),
          height: 100.0,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: latestList.length, itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              width: 100.0,
              height: 100.0,
              child: Card(
                elevation: 3.0,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                  child: Align(
                    child: Image.network(latestList[index],fit: BoxFit.cover,width: 100.0,height: 100.0,),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0,bottom: 10.0,top: 25.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('PlugXR Markers',textAlign: TextAlign.left ,overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 22.0),)
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(

          child: Container(

            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 0.0),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: StaggedWidget(),
          ),
        )
      ],
    )


  );
```

}**